# Drupal generates long links

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

My drupal site generates long links like:

```
example.com/drupal/blog/what-we-do/solutions/about-us/
```

This link works and shows the blog page:

```
example.com/drupal/blog/
```

how can i get rid off these kind of links?

Answer (score 1):

Disable the **path** module in your Drupal installation.

If you want to keep using the path module and delete only some of your aliases visit the page *admin/config/search/path* and delete whatever you want.

When you create new content you can uncheck the automatic alias generation and blank the text field where you write the alias.

You will still be able to access the content by using *node/[NODE_ID]*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that automatically depending on the type of content, I think you can use [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto)

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without requiring the user to manually specify the path alias.

Comment: I would suggest pathauto as well. It allows you to really trim down URLs and use a schema that makes more sense to you, using tokens. It's very flexible but requires some thought and experimentation.